# How can i change the time zone in webapp service for windows containers

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I wanted to change the timezone of web app service. I tried using WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE, but this app setting only worked for webapp as a code but not for windows container webapp.

Is there any possible solution for changing timezone in windows container webapp?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the ways to set the time zone in the docker container or Dockerfile [here](https://bobcares.com/blog/change-time-in-docker-container/#targetText=1.,after%20connecting%20to%20the%20container.&targetText=Though%20the%20time%20zone%20change,for%20the%20time%20to%20change.).

You can see this relate post.

[Is there a way to change date of Azure App Service which had a linux based container deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524500/is-there-a-way-to-change-date-of-azure-app-service-which-had-a-linux-based-conta)